# Should I Encrypt my Wallet for Cold Storage?

Tags: wallet, security, encryption, bitcoin-qt-setup

I understand that the Bitcoin QT wallet is already encrypted to some extent when I use a password. Is it best-practice to further encrypt the wallet file for long term storage?

Answer (score 2):

From [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_encryption):

> Wallet encryption uses AES-256-CBC to encrypt only the private keys
> that are held in a wallet. The keys are encrypted with a master key
> which is entirely random. This master key is then encrypted with
> AES-256-CBC with a key derived from the passphrase using SHA-512 and
> OpenSSL's EVP_BytesToKey and a dynamic number of rounds determined by
> the speed of the machine which does the initial encryption (and is
> updated based on the speed of a computer which does a subsequent
> passphrase change).

This means that it doesn't encrypt metadata or pubkeys.
If you want to achieve a greater degree of security and privacy, I recommend to further encrypt the wallet file.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Questions on rounds: if the dynamic number of rounds is based on the machine's capabilities, how does Bitcoin QT know the number of rounds needed to decrypt when opening the same wallet on a different machine? Are the number of rounds stored in the wallet file? If so, are they unencrypted?